Hay, the close question procedure is missing something
I wanted to identify a question for closing due to that it belongs in another SE.  The dumb thing doesn't let me choose the correct SE.  Why can't I choose another SE, like the math SE, for the destination of the question?


I think only mods get to select an arbitrary other SE site for migration to another site.

I think this is a bug.  If we get to suggest and vote to close questions because the question belongs in another SE, we should be able to specify what SE it belongs in and see if other voters agree.
